# Is it normal to have a blinking white underbar for a long time while trying to install Ubuntu on Mac?

Tags: 12.04, boot, boot-failure

When trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a disk, I elected to boot from the disk I mounted the ISO onto.  After a simple load screen with a small graphic at the bottom center, it went to a quickly flashing underbar on a black screen and has been here for some time.

Any thoughts as to what is going on?